# JAVA -version still showing 1.8 after updating to 11 on LINUX

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java-11

I have updated my Java version to 11 and when I do "java -version" it's still showing old version( 1.8).

OS : Ubuntu 20.04.3

java version "1.8.0_321"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 8.1.085)
SAP Java Server VM (build 8.1.085 11.0.14+000, Jan 28 2022 11:56:08 - 81_REL - optU - linux amd64 - 6 - bas2:332131 (mixed mode))

Answer (score 4):

You may use: `sudo update-alternatives --config java`.
It'll show you the available java versions so you can update your path.

Comment: sudo update-alternatives --config java
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
Nothing to configure.

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-am64/

Comment: java -version
java version "1.8.0_321"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 8.1.085)
SAP Java Server VM (build 8.1.085 11.0.14+000, Jan 28 2022 11:56:08 - 81_REL - optU - linux amd64 - 6 - bas2:332131 (mixed mode))

Comment: Still getting old version, anything wrong in above steps?

Comment: How have you installed your java-11 ?

Comment: Yes, even [sudo update-alternatives --config java] giving this output [/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java]

Comment: "How" not "have you".. Anyway, try this: ```sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jre-headless``` followed by ```sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk```. After this, try ```java -version``` if it's still 1.8, try the update-alternatives.

Comment: Also, tell me what ```which java``` outputs please.

Comment: Done both and still showing version 1.8. java version "1.8.0_321"

Comment: What does ```which java``` outputs ?